# Problema para cerrar o minimizar app para Windows Phone 8.1 en C#

Tags: windows-phone

He estando creando una aplicación en Visual Studio 2015 para Windows Phone 8.1 en el lenguaje C#. He creado dos páginas, Main Page y Page 2. Cuando estoy en Page 2 y al dar clic en el emulador al botón de retroceso, minimizaba la aplicación. Le añadí `Using windows.phone.ui.input` y esto:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.IO; using System.Linq; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime; 
using Windows.Foundation; 
using Windows.Foundation.Collections; 
using Windows.UI.Xaml; 
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls; 
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives; 
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data; 
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input; 
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media; 
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation; 
using Windows.Phone.UI.Input; 
// La plantilla de elemento Página en blanco está documentada en http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=390556

namespace Cuentos_Infantiles {
    /// <summary>
    /// Página vacía que se puede usar de forma independiente o a la que se puede navegar dentro de un objeto Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
    {
        public BlankPage1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public object NavigationService { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Se invoca cuando esta página se va a mostrar en un objeto Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Datos de evento que describen cómo se llegó a esta página.
        /// Este parámetro se usa normalmente para configurar la página.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        }

        private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void Contenido1_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


        }

    } 
}
```

y al depurarlo nuevamente, regresa a la página anterior como quiero. 
Pero resulta que al estar en Main Page (pagina inicial), el botón de retroceso no responde ni minimiza o cierra la aplicación.

Éste es el código de Main Page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.Phone.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// La plantilla de elemento Página en blanco está documentada en http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=391641

namespace Cuentos_Infantiles
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Página vacía que se puede usar de forma independiente o a la que se puede navegar dentro de un objeto Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Se invoca cuando esta página se va a mostrar en un objeto Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Datos de evento que describen cómo se llegó a esta página.
        /// Este parámetro se usa normalmente para configurar la página.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Preparar la página que se va a mostrar aquí.

            // TODO: Si la aplicación contiene varias páginas, asegúrese de
            // controlar el botón para retroceder del hardware registrándose en el
            // evento Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed.
            // Si usa NavigationHelper, que se proporciona en algunas plantillas,
            // el evento se controla automáticamente.
        }

        private void Hyperlinkbutton_101_dalmatas_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
        }
    }
}
```

Por favor, necesito ayuda ya que solo quiero minimizar la aplicación como las demás al dar clic en el botón de retroceso.

¿Me falta algún código o qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Hola Alexis, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor, lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre esta comunidad (y así ganar tu primera medalla).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Llevo sin programar para Windows Phone un buen tiempo, pero te diría que el problema está aquí:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
}

private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

En `OnNavigatedTo` estás indicando que cuando se pulse el botón de atrás, debe llamarse a `HardwareButtons_BackPressed` donde lo que se hace es que se va a la Main Page y se cancela el evento (con el `e.Handled = true`).

Ese código no debería ir en el código de Page 2 (o de ninguna página), sino en el código general de la aplicación (App.xaml.cs) porque estás indicando un comportamiento global (cuando se pulse atrás, navegar al Main Page) y además porque corres el riesgo de que se añada varias veces (estás haciendo `+=`) y el comportamiento y rendimiento de tu aplicación se verá afectado.

Luego, ahí sólo estás controlando que se vuelva a la Main Page y no se haga otra acción, pero como es un evento global, eso también va a ocurrir cuando ya estés en el Main Page... quedándote en una aplicación sin salida (el problema descrito).

Debes añadir algo de más lógica. Te bastaría con un `if` que compruebe si estás en la Main Page o no. Algo como este ejemplo (basado en este [otro de Stack Overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31581047/3695983)):

```
private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)

    // obtenemos el frame actual
    Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    // si se puede ir atrás, entonces ir atrás y parar los eventos
    if (frame.CanGoBack)
    {
        frame.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias , muchisimas gracias amigo. Me funcionó. Conoces algún libro o sitio web que explique el desarrollo de Windows Phone? Saludos

Comment: Hola, pude añadí lo que me dijiste y si funciona bien. Pero en Page 2, el contenido de TextBlock se congela luego de entrar dos veces a esa pagina. Es decir, el contenido esta dentro de un ScrollViewer y deja de responder. No sucedia eso hasta que agregue los codigos que escribiste

Comment: @AlexisHerreraBilora Cuando programaba para WP8 usaba el sitio oficial de Microsoft y Stack Overflow como referencia. No usé ningún libro. Sobre el nuevo problema, en lugar de poner una respuesta, deberías compartir el código en una nueva pregunta, detallando cuál es el problema.

Comment: Y comparte dónde has puesto el código para `BackPressed`